# Error while CSV-JSON conversion

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, csv

I am using following code but i am getting error: JSON is undefined.Any clue?

```
<html>  

<head>  

    <title>Demo - Covnert JSON to CSV</title>  

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>  

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/raw/master/json2.js"></script>  



    <script type="text/javascript">  

        // JSON to CSV Converter  

        function ConvertToCSV(objArray) {  

            var array = typeof objArray != 'object' ? JSON.parse(objArray) : objArray;  

            var str = '';  



            for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {  

                var line = '';  

                for (var index in array[i]) {  

                    if (line != '') line += ','  



                    line += array[i][index];  

                }  



                str += line + '\r\n';  

            }  



            return str;  

        }  



        // Example  

        $(document).ready(function () {  



            // Create Object  

            var items = [  

                 {
    "items": [
        {
            "ID": "1",
            "NAME": " John"
        },
        {
             "ID": "2",
            "NAME": " Ashley"
        },
        {
            "ID": "3",
            "NAME": " Joseph"
        }
    ]
}];


            // Convert Object to JSON  

            var jsonObject = JSON.stringify(items);  



            // Display JSON  

            $('#json').text(jsonObject);  



            // Convert JSON to CSV & Display CSV  

            $('#csv').text(ConvertToCSV(jsonObject));  

        });   

    </script>  

</head>  

<body>  

    <h1>  

        JSON</h1>  

    <pre id="json"></pre>  

    <h1>  

        CSV</h1>  

    <pre id="csv"></pre>  



</body>  

</html>
```

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Your CSV conversion is wrong, it gives [object object], [object object], [object object]. See working example here http://jsfiddle.net/sturtevant/vUnF9/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before the for loop add the following line:

```
array = array[0].items;
```

Basically your parsed JSON is an array that contains one object, items, which is itself an array of three objects. You just weren't getting to the correct array.

Answer (score 0):

`JSON.parse` is [not present in outdated browsers](http://caniuse.com/json), most notably, IE7. You're getting that error because the browser is not providing you with `window.JSON`.

Because of this, you're using `json2.js`. However, github does *not* want you hotlinking to files, and so serves it as `text/plain`. This causes the browser not to interpret it as a script, so it never executes, and no `JSON` object is provided.

You need to host `json2.js` yourself, or find and use a CDN.

Comment: Isn't that why OP included the json2.js of Crockford?